# Github workflow pylint: How do I disable all docstring errors warnings?

Tags: github, pylint, pylintrc

I've setup the pylint workflow on GitHub.

The is the path:

`myRepo/.github/workflows/pylint.yml`

I added a pylintrc file in the workflows directory with the following options:

```
[MESSAGES CONTROL]

disable=missing-module-docstring,
        missing-function-docstring,
        missing-class-docstring
```

But now the build fails, so I've done this in the wrong way.

Is it possible to add the options I have in my `pylintrc` file to `pylint.yml`?

#### Yaml file on Github:

```yaml
name: Pylint

on: [push]
  
jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    strategy:
      matrix:
        python-version: ["3.8", "3.9", "3.10"]
    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v3
    - name: Set up Python ${{ matrix.python-version }}
      uses: actions/setup-python@v3
      with:
        python-version: ${{ matrix.python-version }}
    - name: Install dependencies
      run: |
        python -m pip install --upgrade pip
        pip install pylint
    - name: Analysing the code with pylint
      run: |
        pylint $(git ls-files '*.py')
```

I want to disable all docstring warnings.

Comment: You may need to specify the path to the .pylintrc file in the  github action. Either with the PYLINTRC environment variable or the --rcfile=.pylintrc command line argument.

Comment: where do I find the github action? everything is defined in a yaml file, I'm not sure where I'd set the PYLINTRC env variable

Comment: I just noticed that you put pylintrc in the workflows directory. Try putting it in your top level project folder.

Comment: If that doesn't work, you can add the --rcfile=pylintrc argument to the pylint.yml file like this: **pylint --rcfile=pylintrc $(git ls-files '*.py')**

Comment: Thank you very much. Both things have to be done as first I just added the cmd and it couldn't find the rcfile. Now I'm getting an error that pylintrc has no headers, so I added `[MESSAGES CONTROL]` to the top of pylintrc and it's worked. There really isn't any info about doing this for github workflows, and I was fast to get downvoted, do you know why this is a bad question? I really doubt anyone would've answered so many thanks. Can you please write an answer so I can give credit and so other people are helped?

Comment: Done. Glad it's working for you now. It's not clear to me either the reason for the downvote. FWIW, sometimes I have questions and answers that get downvoted for no obvious reason

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that the pylintrc (or sometimes called .pylintrc) file is at the top level of your project.

Theoretically pylint should be able to pick up that location by default, but if it still isn't working, pass in the argument --rcfile=pylintrc to pylint.
For example:

```
pylint --rcfile=pylintrc $(git ls-files '*.py')
```

Please also ensure that the pylintrc file is formatted correctly. This page shows an intial valid configuration:
https://www.getcodeflow.com/pylint-configuration.html

Comment: if using github workflow pylint, there will be a pylint.yml file, the command in the answer will be at the end but without the `--rcfile` option so you have to add that part in, many thanks @opike, I got that all from you, just thought I'd mention the yaml file.

Comment: look at the reason for closing, utter power play, I have done everything the reasons they have mentioned that caused this problem to be closed, mod on cloud 9 right now.

Comment: Yeah, it doesn't make sense to me either. You gave me enough info to where I was able to help.

Comment: Exactly and you were able to infer about 3 sub solutions to solve my problem, which shows you understood the problem from the info given. Is there a way to challenge this?

Comment: I don't know how clear it needs to be when I've stated in numerous places that I want to disable docstring warnings including the title